# Error when trying to set Players displayname on chat event (Minecraft, Spigot)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, minecraft, bukkit

I am fairly new to Java and programming Minecraft plugins. I would like the chat listener to check it the player's name is in the config and then set the display name to that, but if the player's name is not in the config, then I would like it to just set the players name.

This is my Chat Listener:

```
package me.purp.servercore.listeners;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.AsyncPlayerChatEvent;

import me.purp.servercore.Main;
import me.purp.servercore.utils.Utils;

public class ServerChat implements Listener
{
    private Main plugin;

    public ServerChat(Main plugin)
    {
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, plugin);
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void Chat(AsyncPlayerChatEvent event)
    {

        String message = event.getMessage();

        Player player = event.getPlayer();

        if (!plugin.getConfig().contains(player.getName())) {
            event.setFormat(Utils.color("&7" + player.getDisplayName() + " &7&l» &r" + message));
        } else if (plugin.getConfig().contains(player.getName())) {
            event.setFormat(Utils.color("&7" + plugin.getConfig().getString(player.getName()) + " &7&l» &r" + message));
        }
    }

}
```

This is my nickname class:

```
package me.purp.servercore.commands;

import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.FileConfiguration;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

import me.purp.servercore.Main;
import me.purp.servercore.utils.Utils;

public class PlayerNick implements CommandExecutor
{
    private Main plugin;

    public PlayerNick(Main plugin)
    {
        this.plugin = plugin;

        plugin.getCommand("nick").setExecutor(this);
    }

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args)
    {
        FileConfiguration config = plugin.getConfig();

        if (!(sender instanceof Player))
        {
            sender.sendMessage(Utils.color(config.getString("PlayerEntityFalse")));
            return true;
        }

        Player player = (Player) sender;

        if (player.hasPermission("core.nick"))
        {
            if (args.length == 0)
            {
                player.sendMessage(Utils.color("&cYou cannot have a blank nickname!"));
                return true;
            }

            String nick = "";
            for (String arg : args)
            {
                nick += arg + " ";
            }

            player.sendMessage(Utils.color("&7Your nickname is now: " + nick));
            config.set(player.getName(), nick);
            plugin.saveConfig();
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

This is my error:

```
Could not pass event AsyncPlayerChatEvent to Core v0.2
org.bukkit.event.EventException: null
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:306) ~[spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-2cf50f0-8166d17]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.java:62) ~[spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-2cf50f0-8166d17]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.fireEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:500) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-2cf50f0-8166d17]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:482) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-2cf50f0-8166d17]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.PlayerConnection.chat(PlayerConnection.java:1319) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-2cf50f0-8166d17]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:1257) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-2cf50f0-8166d17]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.PacketPlayInChat$1.run(PacketPlayInChat.java:39) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-2cf50f0-8166d17]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at me.purp.servercore.listeners.ServerChat.Chat(ServerChat.java:29) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:302) ~[spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-2cf50f0-8166d17]
        ... 11 more
```

Comment: in the class `ServerChat`, the field `plugin` is never being initialized (like it is done in the constructor of `PlayerNick`)

Answer (score 1):

Like said in the comment from Carlos under this post:

You haven't set `this.plugin = plugin` in your `ServerChat` class.

---

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at me.purp.servercore.listeners.ServerChat.Chat(ServerChat.java:29)
```

At line 29:

```java
if (!plugin.getConfig().contains(player.getName())) {
```

so either

- `plugin` or
- `plugin.getConfig()` or
- `player`

is null. Try to print out these variables and tell us which one is null.

My toughts:
Maybe you dont have your config saved with saveDefaultConfig() in the onEnable method. `plugin` shouldn't be null because then there should be a problem at the constructor when registering the listener. Also the `player` normally isn't null so the problem should be at the config.

Comment: it seems like `plugin` is never set in that class, probably missing in the constructor...

Comment: oh wait, ur right, im adding this to my post contributing you!

Comment: but leave your explanation - it's the way to go and find the error